# Finding various char's within a String

Tags: java, string, char

I have a basic String variable that contains the letter x a total of three times.
I have attempted to find x within the String using charAt, and then print the char and the next two characters next to it.

I have hit a snag within my code and would appreciate any help.

Here is my code.

```
public class StringX{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String ss = "xarxatxm";
        char first = ss.charAt(0);
        char last == ss.charAt(3);

        if(first == "x"){ 
            String findx = ss.substring(0, 2);
        }
        if(last == "x"){
            String findX = ss.substring(3, 5);
        }

        System.out.print(findx + findX);
    }
}
```

Also, is there a way to implement the for loop to cycle through the String looking for x also?

I just need some advice to see where my code is going wrong.

Comment: `"x"` is a string and `'x'` is a char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find characters using `charAt` - it's for *getting* a character once you know where  it is.

> Is there a way to implement the for loop to cycle through the String looking for x also?

You need to use [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29) for finding positions of characters. Pass the initial position which is the position of the last `x` that you found so far to get the subsequent position.

For example, the code below

```
String s = "xarxatxm";
int pos = -1;
while (true) {
    pos = s.indexOf('x', pos+1);
    if (pos < 0) break;
    System.out.println(pos);
}
```

[prints `0 3 6`](http://ideone.com/yot1Pq) for the three positions of `'x'` in the string.

Comment: Nice one! I will take this code and manipulate to produce what is required. I will let you know how I get on and thank you.